# Using select in where clause and inner join

Tags: inner-join

I have tree tables:

**1.** *Items*

itm_code, itm_gsm, itm_size

**2.** *LotMaster*

lot_code, itm_code, po_number, lot_number

**3.** *LotItems*

lot_itm_code, lot_code, lot_itm_qty

How can i get itm_gsm, itm_qty, lot_itm_qty for the user input value of po_number and lot_number?

Comment: Can you show us what you have come up with so far already?

Comment: sql_lotitems = "SELECT Items.itm_gsm, Items.itm_size, LotItems.lot_itm_qty
                        FROM (Items
                        INNER JOIN LotItems ON Items.itm_code = LotItems.itm_code)
                        WHERE LotItems.lot_code = (SELECT LotMaster.lot_code WHERE LotMaster.po_number =" & ponum And "LotMaster.lot_number =" & lotnum & ")"

Comment: it is giving an error message " Conversion from string "SELECT Items.itm_gsm, Items.itm_" to type 'Long' is not valid."

Answer (score 0):

## try this:

```
select itm.Itm_gsm,itm.itm_qty ltm.lot_itm_qty from Items itm inner join LotMaster lm on lm.itm_code=itm.itm_code inner join LotItems ltm on ltm.lot_code=lm.lot_code where lm.po_number=@po_number and lm.lot_number=@lot_number;
```

Comment: Tried the above but got an error message "Conversion from string "SELECT Items.itm_gsm, Items.itm_" to type 'Long' is not valid."

Comment: sql_lotitems = "SELECT Items.itm_gsm, Items.itm_size, LotItems.lot_itm_qty
                        FROM Items
                        INNER JOIN LotMaster ON LotMaster.itm_code = Items.itm_code
                        INNER JOIN LotItems ON LotItems.lot_code = LotMaster.lot_code
                        WHERE LotMaster.po_number =" & ponum And "LotMaster.lot_number = " & lotnum

Comment: Dim ponum As Object = dgv_lotlist.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
        Dim lotnum As Object = dgv_lotlist.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value

Comment: ponum and lotnum are the variables to which values are assigned upon double clicking on  a data grid view per above.

Comment: doing it in vb.net

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "SELECT Items.itm_gsm, Items.itm_" to type 'Long' is not valid.

Comment: i don't have your complete code. u have only asked for the sql query in your question. How can i tell you the issues with your code as well. You have to figure it out at your level.

Comment: Private Sub dgv_lotlist_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv_lotlist.CellDoubleClick
        Dim ponum As Object = dgv_lotlist.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
        Dim lotnum As Object = dgv_lotlist.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value
        shwlotitems(ponum, lotnum)

    End Sub

Comment: Private Sub shwlotitems(ponum, lotnum)
        Dim ds_lotitems As New DataSet
        Dim da_lotitems As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim sql_lotitems As String

Comment: sql_lotitems = "SELECT Items.itm_gsm, Items.itm_size, LotItems.lot_itm_qty
                        FROM Items
                        INNER JOIN LotMaster ON LotMaster.itm_code = Items.itm_code
                        INNER JOIN LotItems ON LotItems.lot_code = LotMaster.lot_code
                        WHERE LotMaster.po_number =" & ponum And "LotMaster.lot_number = " & lotnum

        con.Open()

Comment: da_lotitems = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql_lotitems, con)
        da_lotitems.Fill(ds_lotitems, "Lot Items")

        con.Close()

    End Sub

Comment: i don't know much about vb and oledb. please accept or reject my edit

Comment: yeah surely. i had made an edit on your question. you can either accept it or reject

Comment: I looked for that 'edit' Kittu, but I could not find it... it is okay to leave it as is?

Comment: you must be recieved some edit request? if you dont want this edit just reject it,

Comment: i did not receive such a request

Comment: i have submitted an edit and it is showing me status pending. but its ok if you are not able to find this.